# Events webpart - using Category search on 'See all' option

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part

I'm using the Events webpart on our intranet. We've got a set of agreed categories populated in the choices drop down, and the webpart is configured to pull in 'All sites' for the Source. The problem I'm having is that when 'See All' is selected the Category free text isn't responsive. The user has to type in the exact wording of the category to return any results, and the Category doesn't pre-populate with any suggestions. I've switched caching on, but any advice on how to make it more user friendly and responsive would be gratefully received.

Comment: Per my knowledge, there is on option to change modern events web part behavior. You could make the suggestion in the feedback portal. https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/